# Javascript - Uncaught TypeError:string is not a function

Tags: javascript

Im having some trouble with a javascript code for a tic tac toe webpage. Whenever I make a move this error occurs in the console:
`Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function`
Here is my webpage's link :
http://www.cgscomputing.com/36558/test.html
And here is the code:

```
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>

    <table>

        <tr>
            <td id = "spot1"></td>
            <td id = "spot2"></td>
            <td id = "spot3"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id = "spot4"></td>
            <td id = "spot5"></td>
            <td id = "spot6"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id = "spot7"></td>
            <td id = "spot8"></td>
            <td id = "spot9"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <!---Contains the message telling which players' turn it currently is-->        
    <p id = "footer"></p>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

        //select a random number to decide which player goes first
        var randNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2));

        //list which contains what is printed to the document concerning the turn
        var beginTurn = ["Computer's ", "Your "];
        var turn = beginTurn[randNum];

        //print who's turn it is underneath the board
        var footer = document.getElementById("footer");
        footer.innerHTML = turn + " turn";

        //array containing all the possible combinations through which a player can win the game
        var possibleCombinations = [[2, 5, 8], [3, 5, 7], [6, 5, 4], [9, 5, 1], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [3, 6, 9]];

        //through the game, keeps track if there is a winner or not
        var won = false;

        //when true, the player will not be able to place another marker on the board, and will have to wait for the computer to put in a marker first
        var computerTurn = false;

        //function for the computer to find a spot to place its marker in the board
        function findLocation() {

            for (var n = 0; n < 8; n++) {

                //The computer first checks if it can win by placing one more insertMarker on the board

                if ((document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][0]).innerHTML == "O") && (document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][1]).innerHTML == "O") && (document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][2]).innerHTML == "")) {
                    return possibleCombinations[n][2];
                    break;
                }
                else if ((document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][0]).innerHTML == "O") && (document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][1]).innerHTML == "") && (document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][2]).innerHTML == "O")) {
                    return possibleCombinations[n][1];
                    break;
                }
                else if ((document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][0]).innerHTML == "") && (document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][1]).innerHTML == "O") && (document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][2]).innerHTML == "O")) {
                    return possibleCombinations[n][0];
                    break;
                }

                //If the computer cannot win, it checks if it can block the human player

                else if ((document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][0]).innerHTML == "X") && (document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][1]).innerHTML == "X") && (document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][2]).innerHTML == "")) {
                    return possibleCombinations[n][2];
                    break;
                }
                else if ((document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][0]).innerHTML == "X") && (document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][1]).innerHTML == "") && (document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][2]).innerHTML == "X")) {
                    return possibleCombinations[n][1];
                    break;
                }
                else if ((document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][0]).innerHTML == "") && (document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][1]).innerHTML == "X") && (document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[n][2]).innerHTML == "X")) {
                    return possibleCombinations[n][0];
                    break;
                }

            }

            //=======
            //If it cannot Win or Block, the compter chooses a random spot on the board to place a insertMarker on.

            //An empty array to contain all the avaliable spots on the board
            avaliableSpots = [];

            //The for loop adds all the avaliable spots from the board into the array

            for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                var spot = "spot" + i;
                if (document.getElementById(spot).innerHTML == "") {
                    avaliableSpots.push(i);
                }
            }

            //A random number is generated and it is used to find a spot on the board from the avaliable spots contained in the array
            var randomSpot = Math.floor((Math.random() * (avaliableSpots.length)));
            return avaliableSpots[randomSpot];
        }

        //this function places the marker of the player and the computer on the board
        function insertMarker(insertMarker, spot) {

            if (won == false) {

                if (document.getElementById("spot" + spot).innerHTML == "") {

                    if (insertMarker == "X" && computerTurn == false) {

                        document.getElementById("spot" + spot).innerHTML = insertMarker;
                        footer.innerHTML = "Computer's turn";
                        turn = "Computer's ";
                        computerTurn = true;

                        //Sets a delay of 1 second before the computer places its marker
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            insertMarker("O", findLocation());
                            }, 1000);

                    } else if (insertMarker == "O") {

                        document.getElementById("spot" + spot).innerHTML = insertMarker;
                        computerTurn = false;
                        footer.innerHTML = "Your turn";
                        humanturn();

                    }

                    winner();
                }

            } 

        }

        //Function for the human player's turn. When the player selects a spot on the board, the insertMarker function is called, with the parameters X and the number of the spot.
        function humanturn() {
            //when the human player clicks on an empty spot, the insertMarker function is called with the parameters "x" and the number of the box
            document.getElementById("spot1").onclick = function() {insertMarker("X", 1)};
            document.getElementById("spot2").onclick = function() {insertMarker("X", 2)};
            document.getElementById("spot3").onclick = function() {insertMarker("X", 3)};
            document.getElementById("spot4").onclick = function() {insertMarker("X", 4)};
            document.getElementById("spot5").onclick = function() {insertMarker("X", 5)};
            document.getElementById("spot6").onclick = function() {insertMarker("X", 6)};
            document.getElementById("spot7").onclick = function() {insertMarker("X", 7)};
            document.getElementById("spot8").onclick = function() {insertMarker("X", 8)};
            document.getElementById("spot9").onclick = function() {insertMarker("X", 9)};
        }

        //This functions checks if there is a winner
        function winner() {

            for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

                if ((document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[i][0]).innerHTML == "O") && (document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[i][1]).innerHTML == "O") && (document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[i][2]).innerHTML == "O")) {
                    footer.innerHTML = "COMPUTER WINS";
                    footer.style.color = "red";
                    document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[i][0]).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                    document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[i][1]).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                    document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[i][2]).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                    won = true;
                    break;
                }

                else if ((document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[i][0]).innerHTML == "X") && (document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[i][1]).innerHTML == "X") && (document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[i][2]).innerHTML == "X")) {
                    footer.innerHTML = "PLAYER WINS";
                    footer.style.color = "red";
                    document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[i][0]).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                    document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[i][1]).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                    document.getElementById("spot" + possibleCombinations[i][2]).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                    won = true;
                    break;

                }

            }

        }

        //If it is the computer's turn, the computer places a insertMarker using the insertMarker function
        if (turn == "Computer's ") {
            document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML = "Computer's turn";
            insertMarker("O", findLocation());
            turn = "Your ";
        }

        //If it is the human player's turn, the player places a insertMarker using the insertMarker function
        else if (turn == "Your ") {
            document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML = "Your turn";
            humanturn();
            turn = "Computer's ";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Any code will be much appreciated

Comment: Not really *any* code but the right minimal testable code with which we can reproduce the problem ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've called the method the same name as a parameter, so when you make the recursive call you're calling the parameter which is either "O" or "X" - not the function. Rename one of them and it should resolve this problem

EDIT: should have said which method. it's 'insertMarker'